# Javafx dependencies not getting downloaded from mavencentral() in gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, javafx

I am trying to create a Java Desktop application using Spring Boot - JavaFX - Gradle by integrating using JavaFX weaver in eclipse. But the dependencies for Java FX libraries (javafx-controls, javafx-base ..) are not getting downloaded through the gradle from mavencentral, but other libraries of Spring boot, fxweaver, my sql all gets downloaded correctly.
versions: Spring boot - 3.0.4, Java fx - 17.0.6, Java - 17 , gradle - 7.6.1

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}


group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'net.rgielen:javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter:1.3.0'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
//below javafx libraries are not getting downloaded
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx:17.0.6'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-base:17.0.6'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17.0.6'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:17.0.6'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:17.0.6'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-swing:17.0.6'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-media:17.0.6'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-web:17.0.6'
}
```

I have tried adding the jars manually and it works. But then during development in eclipse, I am unable to see proposals/ comments for methods of components of Java FX libraries as it doesn't have the source files attached. Hence am trying to download it through Gradle. Has someone tried this before. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the JavaFX plugin for Gradle.  I think it's the recommended way to do this.

Comment: Because JavaFX has platform-specific native code that's embedded in the JARs published to Maven Central, you have to use the correct classifier. Unfortunately, Gradle doesn't seem to handle classifiers well. But, for instance, you should have `'org.openjfx:javafx-base:17.0.6:win'` for the Windows distribution. Without the classifier I believe it just downloads an empty JAR file. However, instead of doing this manually, consider using the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` Gradle plugin. And/or using a local JavaFX SDK. Or using a JDK distribution that includes JavaFX.

Comment: Need both the plugin and the module part together. Somehow I missed to apply them both. I will just answer it and provide the build.gradle file, might be useful for someone. Also the ':win' is not mandatory, gradle automatically did it for me. It downloads both jars. Thanks @DaveB and Slaw for the quick response. You guys saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working build.gradle file. I was missing either the plugin and/or the module part during

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "17.0.6"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.swing', 'javafx.media', 'javafx.graphics']
    configuration = 'compileOnly'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    implementation 'net.rgielen:javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-base:17.0.6:win'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17.0.6:win'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:17.0.6:win'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:17.0.6:win'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-swing:17.0.6:win'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-media:17.0.6:win'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-web:17.0.6:win'
    
}
```

Comment: Note if you have the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` Gradle plugin applied, then you should not have any JavaFX dependences declared in the `dependencies` block.